# logstash: Want to match against "single grok pattern" and "multiple grok patterns" in same filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My logfile lines look like below.

```
[2020-07-10T10:00:04.979+00:00] [app_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [report-thread] [tid: 1346887] [userId: user10.id2] start-getchunk: Report=/Report Folder Path/Report name, TemplateName=Template1004, OutFormat=excel, Locale=en_US
[2020-07-10T10:00:25.085+00:00] [app_server2] [NOTIFICATION] [report-thread] [tid: 1346887] [userId: user1.id1] end-getchunk: Report=/Report Folder Path/Report name, TemplateName=Template2007, OutFormat=html, Locale=en_US
[2020-07-10T10:00:25.080+00:00] [app_server2] [NOTIFICATION] [report-thread] [tid: 1346887] [userId: user2.id1][
    Start report processing details
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Report path: /Report Folder Path/Report name
    Datamodel name: /Report Folder Path/Datamodel name
    User name: user2
    Output format: 1
    chunk size limit: 524288000
    -----------------------------------------------------
    End report processing details
]
[Log lines with some other patterns]
```

I want to have below kinds of match patterns in my logstash configuration file to match different lines.

```
(a) match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\sstart-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
(b) match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\send-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
(c) to match a multiline having this match
    break_on_match => false
    match => {
        "message => [
            "Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)",
            "Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
            "User name: (?<user_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
            (?<event_type>Start report processing details)
        ]
    }
(d) other n numbers of matches like the one mentioned in points (a) & (b) above
```

For now, let's assume I have only (a), (b) & (c) in my config.

My config looks similar to below (with the sequence of "match =>" lines changed).

```
filter{
    grok{
        break_on_match => false
        ## single grok pattern match
        match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\sstart-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
        match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\send-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
        ## multple grok pattern match
        match => {
            "message => [
                "Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)",
                "Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
                "User name: (?<user_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
                (?<event_type>Start report processing details)
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Now the problem statement: -**
The config matches the pattern of only THE LAST of the three "match =>" mentioned in the configuration file.
So, if in config file

```
[A] the sequence of "match =>" lines are (a) -> (b) -> (c) (as shown in above config): it matches patterns for only (c).
[B] the sequence of "match =>" lines are (c) -> (b) -> (a): it matches patterns for only (a).
[C] the sequence of "match =>" lines are (c) -> (a) -> (b): it matches patterns for only (b).
```

But, I want all (a), (b), (c) to be matched in the input.

Also, I want to maintain the match patterns for (a), (b), (c) as it is.
Actually, for (c) I had a grok pattern like (a) and (b). At that time the config was trying to match all of (a), (b), and (c). But because of "_groktimeout" error for (c), changed the pattern to the one mentioned in (c) here [Ref](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-groktimeout-error-for-a-particular-filter-sometimes-need-help-optimizing-the-filter/246342).

To solve the issue, I tried having

- multiple grok{} blocks under same filter{} block AND
- multiple filter{} blocks in the same config file
  to solve the issue by splitting "(a), (b)" and "(c)" in separate blocks. But in the above two cases, it does not generate any output.

I tried another option as shown below. This works, but this is not a performance efficient option.
Hence **looking for a better and more performance efficient option without using the grok inside "if" condition**.

```
filter{
    grok{
        ## single grok pattern match
        match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\sstart-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
        match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] (?<event_type>\send-getchunk): Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
        match => {  "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timstamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}] \[%{WORD:log_level}] %{GREEDYDATA}(?<event_type>Start report processing details)"}
        if " Start report processing details" in [event_type]{
            grok {
                break_on_match => false
                ## multple grok pattern match
                match => {
                    "message => [
                        "Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)",
                        "Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
                        "User name: (?<user_name>[^,\r\n]*)",
                        (?<event_type>Start report processing details)
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expected output is like below and for this i'm removing few fields in my configuration file.

```
{"tags":["reportlog"],"userId":"user10.id2","process_timestamp":"2020-07-10T10:00:25.085+00:00","thread_type":"report-thread","template_name":"Template2007","log_level":"NOTIFICATION","event_type":"end-getchunk","output_format":"html","tid":"199163","app_server":"app_server2","report_name":"/Report Folder Path/Report name"}
{"tags":["reportlog"],"userId":"user1.id1","process_timestamp":"2020-07-10T10:00:04.979+00:00","thread_type":"report-thread","template_name":"Template1004","log_level":"NOTIFICATION","event_type":"start-getchunk","output_format":"excel","tid":"800760","app_server":"app_server1","report_name":"/Report Folder Path/Report name"}
{"tags":["multiline","reportlog"],"userId":["user2.id1"],"report_path":"/Report Folder Path/Report name", "process_timestamp":["2020-07-10T10:00:25.080+00:00"],"datamodel_name":"/Report Folder Path/Datamodel name","thread_type":"report-thread","log_level":"NOTIFICATION","event_type":"Start report processing details","tid":["812409"],"app_server":"app_server2"}
```

.
[1]: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-groktimeout-error-for-a-particular-filter-sometimes-need-help-optimizing-the-filter/246342

Comment: Update your question with an example of the message that you want to parse and the expected result. Without seeing how your message looks like it is har to see what is the problem.

Comment: @leandrojmp, Updated the question. But basically I want all three filters (a), (b), (c) mentioned to filter messages from the input file.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your first two messages is that one has the string `start-getchunck` and the other has the string `end-getchunck` and you are saving this string to the same field for both types of message, so your grok patterns **a** and **b** are basically the same.

The following pattern will match those two types of message.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}\] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] %{DATA:event_type}: Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)
```

Instead of using `(?<event_type>\sstart-getchunk):` and `(?<event_type>\send-getchunk):`, use `%{DATA:event_type}:`.

For your multline log, since you didn't share your `input` config, I used the following multine code config to reproduce.

```
codec => multiline {
    pattern => "^\["
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
}
```

The `grok` config you are using for this log is wrong.

Having this:

```
grok {
    match => { 
        "message" => [
            "Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)",
            "Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is the same of having this configuration:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)" }
    match => { "message" => "Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)" }
}
```

What you need is a pattern that match all the fields in your message, the pattern below will match your multiline log.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}\] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\]%{DATA}(?<event_type>Start report processing details)%{DATA}Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)%{DATA}Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)%{DATA}User name: (?<user_name>[^,\r\n]*)"
```

Also, you need to set `break_on_match` to `true`, if your line already had a pattern match there is no need to test it against other pattern, it will only add more processing to your pipeline.

The following `filter` will match all your example lines.

```
filter{
    grok {
        break_on_match => true
        match => {  "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}\] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\] %{DATA:event_type}: Report=(?<report_name>[^,]*), TemplateName=(?<template_name>[^,]*), OutFormat=(?<output_format>[^,]*), Locale=(?<locale>[^,]*)" }
        match => {  "message" => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:process_timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:app_server}\] \[%{WORD:log_level}] \[%{DATA:thread_type}\] \[tid: %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[userId: %{DATA:userId}\]%{DATA}(?<event_type>Start report processing details)%{DATA}Report path: (?<report_path>[^,\r\n]*)%{DATA}Datamodel name: (?<datamodel_name>[^,\r\n]*)%{DATA}User name: (?<user_name>[^,\r\n]*)" }
    }
}
```

The `^` in the begging of the patterns is to anchor the position of your message, if for some reason your message do not start with an `[`, `grok` will not even try to parse it.

Since `grok` relies on regex it can have performance problems, if you still continue to get timeout errors it would be better to change your approach and start using conditionals to parse some messages.

You can try to parse all the common fields with one `grok`, save the different parts of the message in another field and use conditionals to direct this field to the correct `grok`, this performs better than having one `grok` that tries to match everything.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. 
About the start/end thing could be in a single grok match, yes I know that could be done in a single line. I just had two of these in this example to indicate that I have multiple grok matches.
About the third match (c), the reason I did it that way is [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-groktimeout-error-for-a-particular-filter-sometimes-need-help-optimizing-the-filter/246342).

Comment: Looks like, I made the question a complicated one, while my question is very basic and simple. My apologies for making the question a complicated one. 
**Let me reformat and write the question again.**

Comment: You need to share all the relevant information in your question, not link it to an outside source. The link you shared has nothing to do with the question you asked, is better that you ask a new one with all the relevant information.

Comment: I got some references to why the filter was not working as expected. Below are those.
[Reference1](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-7-grok-filter-plugin-break-on-match-appears-to-be-broken/176578/14)
[Reference2](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-grok-processor-break-on-match-false-needed/96697).
No more help needed for this question.